# C++/SQLite only outputting one row of data

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm having an issue where only one of my 5 test rows will output in C++. My code is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*Definitions*/
sqlite3 *db;
void *arg;
char *err;
const char* stmt = "SELECT * from table";
/*End of Definitions*/

int exec(void *arg, int argc, char **argv, char **column) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << column[i] << ": " << argv[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "------" << endl;
}

int main() {
    int rc = sqlite3_open("test.sqlite", &db); /*Open db "test.sqlite"*/
    if(!rc) {
        while(true) {
            sqlite3_exec(db, stmt, exec, arg, &err);
            if(err) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    /*Ending Stuffz (NOTHING BEYOND THIS POINT)*/
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I am not getting any errors; it is purely just outputting the first row. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: looks like you got a non empty err. what if you try to print out err, what would you get?

Comment: @Shiping I get absolutely nothing

Comment: You seem not to init "err". What happens if you do a `if (err) printf("Nonzero before\n");` before the `sqlite_exec();` ?

Comment: Why is the `sqlite_exec()`in a loop. Going through all result rows is done by sqlite, by executing the callback on each of them, isn't it?

Comment: What is the output of `sqlite3 test.sqlite .dump`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply everyone, @Yunnosch nothing happens, the program still outputs the one row and nothing else is shown.

Comment: @CL. I have a weird setup because otherwise I'm unable to compile at all so sqlite3 isn't recognised as a command by cmd.

Comment: Just [download](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) the tools package.

Comment: @CL. I type said command in and get [this](https://pastebin.com/7D6Ub5Aq)

Comment: This database contains not five but two rows. And the test program will not output anything because the query is not correct SQL. Print the error message you get.

Comment: @CL. I have shortened the database since I made this post and I get no error message.

Comment: You get no error message because the code never bothers to print it.

Comment: @CL. Going of what you have said, I replaced my error outputting line a few lines higher and I now have the error `callback requested query abort`

Comment: What error output line? There is none in the code you've shown. And the only error you get can be "`Error: near "table": syntax error`".

Comment: @CL. It was `cout << err << endl;`, which I added after the `exec();` line.

Answer (score 1):

Just return 0 in the end of exec function

Explanation:

In function 'exec" when it return nothing, the database server acts like the function is terminated by somehow (like something corrupt the function and made an error) so it just stop sending data because the call back function terminated with an error.... so when we return 0 we say that the function "exec" is working normally so it keeps sending data ... and if you return any other integer it will deal with it like the function terminated by an error and stop sending data. I faced the same issue and I solved it by making the callback function (exec) return 0.